# How do I get 'n' number of rows of dates preceded by current date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

Actual Scenario is that, I am providing input as year to forecast data.
suppose if ForecastYear is 2016.

then the result should be

```
-------------
ForecastYear
-------------
2014
2015
2016
-------------
```

Comment: Suppose if ItemA's Sale in 2013 is 100 Quantity n I'm aspecting 10% of sales growth in next year i.e. in 2014
____________________
ITEM | YEAR  | QTY |
--------------------
ITM-A| 2013  | 100 |
ITM-B| 2013  | 200 |
--------------------
if I want to forecast sale data for upto year 2015
Item    |  2013 | 2014 | 2014 |
-------------------------------
Item-A  |  100  | 110  |  121 |--each year qty incrmtd by 10% of its
Item-B  |  200  | 220  |  242 |--previous year qty
--------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @toyear int=2016

;with CTE as
(
select year(getdate()) years
union all
select years+1 from cte where years<@toyear
)
select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a number-table, then it's simple as:

```
DECLARE @ForecastYear int
SET @ForecastYear  = 2016
DECLARE @NumYears int
SET @NumYears  = 3

SELECT TOP (@NumYears) ForecastYear = n 
FROM dbo.Numbers
WHERE n > @ForecastYear - @NumYears
ORDER BY n
```

How you create a number-table:

```
SELECT TOP (1000000) n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers(n)
;
```

[**Generate a set or sequence without loops**](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)